# Merging verts/ filling holes issue

Tags: modeling

This is just an example picture, but I keep running into this problem where i create a vert in edit mode and extrude it, then create faces, then merge the verbs/ filling holes to another object then subdivide it. And this is us the result. I made sure there were no faces in between. please help. I'm using Blender 2.8[image]

Comment: Can you show your normals and display split normals for us .
and can we have a look inside your model to look if there is a face inside ?

Comment: I found an answer to my question. People have asked this question before and it had the solution and I managed to fix it. thank you!